# How to hide chapter numbering in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

I know `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` lets you set the depth of numberings, but I have to number sections and subsections only, not chapters. Is there a one-liner to do this? I have seen some answers to similar problems, but they seem overly complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: The magic keyword is `MWE` ;-)

Comment: You still want the chapters numbered, but just not in the ToC? `secnumdepth` deals with document content, yet you're referring to ToC-related content. Mmmm, please explain. And are you using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) *or* [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) (not both)... they're not really compatible.

Comment: It's the same. In the requirements for my document there are no specifications regarding the numbering of the content. I thought of it as a workaround to hide them from the TOC.

Comment: @Federico: Could you make your question less ambiguous so it's helpful to other people as well? Give an example of the input you would supply, what things will/should look like in your document and what they should look like in the ToC...

Comment: @Federico: Did you want to hide the numbering only or the the complete chapter entries. In the first case, please unaccept my answer, it does not address your request, I've misinterpreted your question then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My mistake. Seems I misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: @Federico: In the meantime I've done some additions, perhaps this is what you wanted ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very fancy and sophisticated package `etoc` by our fellow user jfbu provides the means for this.

By using `\etocsetlevel{level name}{level value}` it's possible to shift the structure level (e.g. *chapter*) to some lower level (say, beyond *subparagraph*) and then restrict the `tocdepth` counter to some value above.

`\etocsetlevel{chapter}{6}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` will do the job.

This affects only the representation in the ToC, not in the main part of the document.

An adjustment of spacings within the ToC might be necessary, this can be achieved with the various `\cft....` commands from the `tocloft` package (not used here)

Please note the difference between `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` counters:

- `tocdepth` decides, which levels are shown in the toc (-1 downto 6) from `part` to `subparagraph` (for standard LaTeX classes)
- `secnumdepth` decides which levels get section numbers in the main document.

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}       
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% Show down to subsubsection
\begin{document}    

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} %for main TOC, only show chapter/section
\etocsetlevel{part}{6} % push away the chapters
\etocsetlevel{chapter}{6}  % push away the chapters, beyond toc depth (4 )
\tableofcontents
\chapter{this is chapter heading}    
  \section{this is section heading}
  \subsection{this is subsection heading}
  \subsubsection{this is subsubsection heading}
  \subsubsection{this is another subsubsection heading}
  \chapter{another chapter}
  \section{this is yet another section} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

If only the numbers of the chapters should be removed (however, not for section 1.1 etc. ), one trick is to patch the `\@chapter` command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% Show down to subsubsection

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{-20pt}% Just some value...

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{%
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    

\tableofcontents

%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{First chapter}
  \section{First section}
  \subsection{First subsection}
  \subsubsection{Even more in the basement}
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{this is yet another section} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :This code entirely removes chapters from toc. The OP wants only to remove chapter numbering in toc, if I've well understood.

Comment: @Bernard: Damn, your right... I misinterpreted ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use a KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses]{scrbook}
\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `titletoc`:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{microtype}

    \usepackage{titletoc}%

      \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\lsstyle\smallskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
      {}%
      {\itshape\bfseries}%numberless%
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%
    %
     \titlecontents{section}[4.25em]{\smallskip}%
      {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}}%numbered
      {\hspace*{-1em}}%numberless
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]%
    %
     \titlecontents{subsection}[7em]{}%
      {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.75em}}%numbered
      {\hspace*{-1em}}%numberless
      {\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter*{INTRODUCTION}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION}

    \chapter{A NICE FIRST CHAPTER}

    \section{An Introductory Section}
    \newpage
    \section{Another Section}
    \subsection{A Boring Subsection }

    \end{document}
```

[image]