# Customizing the TOC of book

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I would like to have in my TOC the following

> I First Chapter
>      I.1 First section
>      I.2 second section 
>   II Second Chapter
>   II.1 First section
>   II.2 second section
>
> Contributions
>
> Contribution I: title of the first paper % May this be an external
>   included pdf
>   Contribution II: title of the first paper

In my following MWE I changed the name of chapter in the contribution part and I put the contribution title in the TOC as an option but instead of e.g. "contribution I: its title" I have "I contribution I: its title".

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\RequirePackage{scrhack} % 

\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
%\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \automark[chapter]{chapter} %\automark[right side]{left side}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
    \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer header


%vll
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}  
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %
\ChNameAsIs  
\ChTitleAsIs  

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter  
        \DOCH
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
     \if@mainmatter % 
      \DOTI{#1}%
    \else%
      \DOTIS{#1}%
    \fi
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{% 
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \DOTIS{#1}
    \vskip -20\p@ 
  }}
\makeatother
%========================

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum}     
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Sec. chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip \textbf{\large   Contributions}\par} 
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Contribution}

\chapter[Contribution I: Paper title]{First paper's title}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter[Contribution II: Paper title]{Second contribution}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

PS: I tried in vain the methods given in answers of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228729)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the KOMA-Script class `scrbook` but without package `fncychap`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}[2017/09/07]% needs version 3.24 or newer
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
\clearpairofpagestyles%
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix,numbers=noenddot,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
\newlength{\ChapterRuleWidth}\setlength{\ChapterRuleWidth}{2pt}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  expandtopt,
  innerskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=60pt,
  font=\normalfont\Huge,
  prefixfont=\bfseries
]{chapter}

\newcaptionname{english}{\contributionname}{Contribution}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=chapter,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  toclevel=\chaptertocdepth,
  tocbeforeskip=1em plus 1pt,
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=1.5em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{chapterentry},
  tocentrynumberformat=\contributiontocnumber,
  tocentrypagenumberformat=\usekomafont{chapterentry},
  toclinefill=\hfill
]{contribution}
\renewcommand\thecontribution{\Roman{contribution}}
\newcommand*\contributiontocnumber[1]{\contributionname\ #1:\hfill}
\renewcommand*\contributionformat{\contributionname\nobreakspace\thecontribution\autodot}
\renewcommand*\contributionmarkformat{\contributionname\ \thecontribution\autodot\enskip}
\automark*[contribution]{contribution}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{}{{%
    \normalsize\rule{\linewidth}{3\ChapterRuleWidth}\\*[-.5\baselineskip]%
    \rule{\linewidth}{\ChapterRuleWidth}\par\nobreak
    }#2}%
  {\normalsize\rule{\linewidth}{\ChapterRuleWidth}\par\nobreak}
  #3
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{\vskip -20pt}{}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{defaulttocdepth}

\newcommand\StartContributions{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=contribution]{section}%
  \addxcontentsline{toc}{part}{Contributions}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=\contributionnumdepth}%
}
\setkomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}
\newcommand\EndContributions{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=chapter]{section}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=\the\value{tocdepth}}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Sec. chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\StartContributions
\contribution{First paper's title}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]
\contribution{Second contribution}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]
\EndContributions

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that the code above needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.24. Update: If you use KOMA-Script version 3.39 or newer replace the deprecated option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` by the new class option `sfdefaults=false`.

If you want/have to use one of the versions 3.21, 3.22 or 3.23 add

```
beforeskip=-1sp,
innerskip=.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=60pt,
font=\normalfont\Huge,
prefixfont=\bfseries,
pagestyle=plain,
```

to the options of `\DeclareNewSectionFormat[...]{contribution}`.

Result:

[image]

[image]

---

But it is also possible to use package `tocbasic` with another class to get the desired result:

Add

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand*\Contribution{%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Contribution}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \bigskip \noindent\textbf{\large Contributions}\protect\par
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry
      [entrynumberformat=\nullfont,numwidth=0pt,pagenumberformat=\textbf]
      {tocline}{chapter}%
    \protect\value{tocdepth}=0%
  }%
  \renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}%
}
```

to the preamble and use `\Contribution` to the document body. This should also work with your special class mentioned in a comment.
Assuming that there is no switch back to normal chapters needed, I did not define an command for the end of the contributions like in my first example. But the example corrects the header entries, too.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\RequirePackage{scrhack} % 

\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
%\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \automark[chapter]{chapter} %\automark[right side]{left side}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
    \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer header


%vll
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}  
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %
\ChNameAsIs  
\ChTitleAsIs  

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter  
        \DOCH
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
     \if@mainmatter % 
      \DOTI{#1}%
    \else%
      \DOTIS{#1}%
    \fi
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{% 
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \DOTIS{#1}
    \vskip -20\p@ 
  }}
\makeatother
%========================

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand*\Contribution{%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Contribution}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \bigskip \noindent\textbf{\large Contributions}\protect\par
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry
      [entrynumberformat=\nullfont,numwidth=0pt,pagenumberformat=\textbf]
      {tocline}{chapter}%
    \protect\value{tocdepth}=0%
  }%
  \renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}%
}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Sec. chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\Contribution

\chapter[Contribution I: Paper title]{First paper's title}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter[Contribution II: Paper title]{Second contribution}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

---

**Update (appendix after contributions)**

In a comment OP asks for changeing back to the normal entry format for appendix chapters.

Then I would use

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand*\Contribution{%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Contribution}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \bigskip \noindent\textbf{\large Contributions}\protect\par
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry
      [entrynumberformat=\nullfont,numwidth=0pt]
      {tocline}{chapter}%
    \protect\value{tocdepth}=0%
  }%
  \renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}%
}
\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \defaultchaptertocstyle
    \protect\value{tocdepth}=\the\value{tocdepth}%
  }%
  \let\chaptermarkformat\defaultchaptermarkformat
}
\newcommand*\defaultchaptertocstyle{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\bfseries,numwidth=1.5em,pagenumberformat=\textbf]
    {tocline}{chapter}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\defaultchaptermarkformat\chaptermarkformat
  \defaultchaptertocstyle
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{xparse}% loads etoolbox

\RequirePackage{scrhack} % 

\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
%\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \automark[chapter]{chapter} %\automark[right side]{left side}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
    \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer header


%vll
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}  
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %
\ChNameAsIs  
\ChTitleAsIs  

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter  
        \DOCH
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
     \if@mainmatter % 
      \DOTI{#1}%
    \else%
      \DOTIS{#1}%
    \fi
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{% 
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \DOTIS{#1}
    \vskip -20\p@ 
  }}
\makeatother
%========================

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand*\Contribution{%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Contribution}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \bigskip \noindent\textbf{\large Contributions}\protect\par
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry
      [entrynumberformat=\nullfont,numwidth=0pt]
      {tocline}{chapter}%
    \protect\value{tocdepth}=0%
  }%
  \renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}%
}
\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \defaultchaptertocstyle
    \protect\value{tocdepth}=\the\value{tocdepth}%
  }%
  \let\chaptermarkformat\defaultchaptermarkformat
}
\newcommand*\defaultchaptertocstyle{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\bfseries,numwidth=1.5em,pagenumberformat=\textbf]
    {tocline}{chapter}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\defaultchaptermarkformat\chaptermarkformat
  \defaultchaptertocstyle
}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Sec. chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\Contribution

\chapter[Contribution I: Paper title]{First paper's title}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter[Contribution II: Paper title]{Second contribution}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\section{An appendix section}
\lipsum
\section {Second appendix section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I am using  [MastersDoctoralThesis.sty class](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

Comment: @LlavDem See my updated answer. You can use `tocbasic` with another class, too.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, it's now almost looking like what I wanted; it works fine with MastersDoctoralThesis class as you mentioned. Is it difficult to define "\EndContributions" ? I have appendices and they are no longer proceded by a letter :(

Comment: After the defined contribution I have: `\chapter*{Conclusion} \phantomsection\addchaptertocentry{Conclusion}\markboth{Conclusion}{Conclusion} ` and then `\appendix` and `\chapter{Appendix}` with its sections. Now I have problem only in the appendix where `A. Appendix title` is replaced by `Appendix title`

Comment: So there is no numbering problem. I will do it tomorow. But note that your special class provides an `\addchap` command. So you can replace your code regarding "Conclusion" by `\addchap{Conclusion}`. It adds the chapter entry and sets the marks for the header automatically.

Comment: OK, I changed a lot of the class and it seems that the command `addchap`  no longer works proprely.

Comment: See my the third version in my updated answer. If there are more issues with changes to your original example, then please ask a follow up question with a new MWE.