# Remove chapter number before section number within TOC only

Tags: cross-referencing, titletoc

I have seen the answer to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44826/95423), but I want more control:

I have *roman* Chapters and *arabic* sections. I want the roman numeral to be hidden from the TOC, and from the **TOC only** (additionally, I will also remove them later from the section titles). The most important is that *I need the cross chapter section **references** to show the chapter number*.

I tried `titletoc` without success (although copying almost identically a command from the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\newcommand{\thesectiononly}{\arabic{section}}  % Do not override \thesection.

% Large bold section titles with section number only
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesectiononly}{24pt}{}

% bold section names in the table of contents, with section number only.
\titlecontents*{section}[12pt]{\bfseries}{\thesectiononly. }{}{\thecontentspage}

\begin{document}

% Here, we should see 1. First section......
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}\label{sec:first-section}

First content.

\section{Second section}

Other content.

\chapter{Second chapter}

\section{section in second chapter}

Last content, referring to section~\ref{sec:first-section}. % Displayed as "I.1"

\end{document}
```

This compiles, but the resulting TOC is:

[image: Imgur]

- How do I get the correct section numbering?
- How do I get default leading dots to the page number?

I know about `tocloft`, but haven't found a way to strip off chapter numbers using it.

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228729/how-to-hide-chapter-numbering-in-table-of-contents).

Comment: Thank you. It's not exactly what I want : I still want chapters to be numbered in the TOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to redefine `\thesection` and `\p@section`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.} 
\makeatother


\begin{document}

% Here, we should see 1. First section......
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}\label{sec:first-section}

First content.

\section{Second section}

Other content.

\chapter{Second chapter}

\section{section in second chapter}

Last content, referring to section~\ref{sec:first-section}. % Displayed as "I.1"

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\p@section` ? Is it described in the Latex macros?

Comment: you ca find it in `source2e`

Comment: Incredible, here is a latex problem solved in 3 simple lines... and this has the added benefit that titlesec and titletoc packages are not needed anymore.

Comment: I am being futile, but now from within a chapter, is there a way to refer to same-chapter sections without the `\p@section` part?... I am using the cleverref package. For example by using a new macro `\localcref`?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong there is. you need to do some tests. I think this was already answered here.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong here you are https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262652/how-to-make-the-enumeration-of-theorem-like-environments-indipendent-from-cross/263185#263185